# Web services hit error, when I using the object as parameter

Tags: c#, json, web-services

I have created a web services, inside the web services, I got the web function which return as the json web format, the following code is the example.

```
<WebMethod()> _
<ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat:=ResponseFormat.Json, UseHttpGet:=True)> _
Public Sub getReligion()
    Dim ObjDBConn As SqlConnection
    Dim ObjReader As SqlDataReader
    Dim ObjAdapter As SqlDataAdapter
    ObjDBConn = ObjWebLiteSvc.InitConsoleDB
    Dim sb As StringBuilder = New StringBuilder()
    Dim religionArray As JArray = New JArray()
    Dim arrResponse As JObject = New JObject()

    Try
        ObjDBConn.Open()
        ObjCmd = New SqlCommand("SELECT Description from dbo.RELIGION", ObjDBConn)
        ObjAdapter = New SqlDataAdapter()
        ObjAdapter.SelectCommand = ObjCmd
        Dim data As DataTable = New DataTable()
        ObjAdapter.Fill(data)

        Dim religionList(data.Rows.Count) As String

        For i = 0 To data.Rows.Count - 1
            religionArray.Add(data.Rows(i).Item("Description").ToString())
        Next

        arrResponse("Status") = "1"
        arrResponse("List") = religionArray
    Catch ex As Exception
        arrResponse("Status") = "0"
        arrResponse("Error") = ex.ToString()
    Finally
        sb.Append("(")
        sb.Append(arrResponse.ToString)
        sb.Append(");")
        Context.Response.Clear()
        Context.Response.ContentType = "application/json"
        Context.Response.Write(sb.ToString)
        Context.Response.End()
        ObjDBConn.Close()
        ObjDBConn.Dispose()
    End Try
End Sub
```

However, in another function, I have create another web function which is not using the json format as the returning format. I think it is fine, but the thing is, when I am using the object as parameter, when I call the getReligion function, it will definitely hit an weird error

```
Public Function RegisterMembership(ByVal membershipList As Object) As Integer
        Return 1
    End Function



System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Index was outside the bounds of the array.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerType..ctor(Type type)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.HttpServerProtocol.Initialize()
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)
```

In the end, after i change the input parameter as string, the getreligion function working fine. How do i allow the object parameter to be insert, when i am using the json returning object on another function?

Comment: Is there any chance that `SELECT Description from dbo.RELIGION` return zero result?

Comment: yes, but the list is confirm to have the data, and when i switch to string parameter format on registerMembership the getReligion return the entire list